# functional testing a service

Tags: php, unit-testing, service, phpunit

I am having trouble testing some simple services that I have in my application. This is my service method:

```
public function createNewCourse($details = array())
    {
        $course = new Course($details);
        $this->persistenceManager->save($course);
    }
```

Basically I am sending an array to this service , create the $course object which sets the properties of the object. After that I call the persistenceManager which basically has a save method which inserts the object in the database. Anyway any tips of how to test this method without actually testing the persistence, because that will be another test.

Comment: this is not a 'unit' test, as you are not testing the 'unit' (method), this is a functional test, as you are testing the functionality of your service and everything inbetween. But thats just a rant :D

Answer (score 3):

If `persistanceManager` is [injected to your object as a dependancy](http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/) then you can create a [mock object](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) to represent it in your tests.

If it is not, then you will have great difficulty unit testing and you should refactor your code to use dependancy injection.

Don't worry, dependancy injection is just a fancy phrase for a pretty simple concept.

You are going to have similar problems unit testing the Course object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stub persistenceManager and provide it to the class that contains the *createNewCourse* method. The stub should look like this:

```
class StubPersistenceManager
{
    private $course;
    public function save($course)
    {
         $this->course = $course;
    }
    public function getCourse()
    {
         return $this->course;
    }
}
```

Ensure you inject an instance of this stub as the $this->persistenceManager in your class that contains the *createNewCourse* method.

In the test you call the *createNewCourse* method and can subsequently fetch the course instance provided to the persistence manager by using the *getCourse* function of the stub.